# Descent on elliptic curves over a quadratic field extension

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I've heard it's possible to find the rank / bound the rank of an elliptic curve using the descent via 2-isogeny method, but over a quadratic field extension (eg. over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$).
Does anyone know if there are any proofs or examples in any books/online of how this method works?

Secondly, I also believe I can do this using Magma - does anyone know the Magma commands for calculating bounds on the rank of an elliptic curve using 2-isogeny over a quadratic field extension?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

This appears in Chapter X of Silverman *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* as Example 4.8 and Proposition 4.9 (where he works over a general number field).

If one wishes to use magma all of this is implemented as `SelmerGroup` in magma. Beware, to do all of this over a general number field Magma uses some very expensive class and unit group calculations, so things can get hairy fast.

As an example:

```
K := QuadraticField(-3);

E := EllipticCurve([0,0,0,1,0]);
E := BaseChange(E, K);

phi := TwoIsogeny(E![0,0]);
phi_hat := DualIsogeny(phi); E_hat := Image(phi);

S := SelmerGroup(phi);
S_hat := SelmerGroup(phi_hat);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Can I ask, with the magma code (I'm new to magma!) how do you output the upper bound for the rank from this set up?

Comment: Well, this computes the size of the $\phi$ and $\hat{phi}$-Selmer groups, so one can use a calculation like that in Silverman X, Prop 6.2 to bound the rank. This is really the essence of descent - find some Selmer groups, and everything else can be computed easily (except Sha)

Comment: I should mention that to speed things up one can use ``SetClassGroupBounds("GRH")`` to assume GRH.